# Django-CKEditor Image Upload File Types

Tags: django, ckeditor5

I have successfully installed Django CKeditor with Uploader but I have one problem I cannot find information about.  When I select Upload I get the standard Windows file browser but it is set to all files.  How can I configure CKUploader to just show supported image file types?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict upload to image only by setting `CKEDITOR_ALLOW_NONIMAGE_FILES = False` in settings.py